# Infinite loop for widget button in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I am trying to implement a button that continuously runs steps of my game. The button involves an infinite loop that runs my step function over and over until the button is released. Problem is it doesn't work. Instead it usually freezes or gives me

```
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Here is the code:

```
def __init__(self, root):
    Frame.__init__(self, root)

    self.butt_released = False

    button3 = Button(self.but_frame, text='Step', width=15, command=lambda :self.step_funct())
    button3.pack(side='right')
    button4 = Button(self.but_frame, text='Run', width=15)
    button4.pack(side='right')
    button4.bind("<Button-1>", lambda :self.run_funct())
    button4.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda :self.butt_release())

def run_funct(self):
    while True:
        self.step_funct()
        time.sleep(1)
        if self.butt_released:
            break
    self.butt_released = False

def butt_release(self):
    self.butt_released = True
```

If anyone can help me fix this then that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the root.after() function, so try:

```
def __init__(self, root):
    Frame.__init__(self, root)
    self.root = root
    self.butt_released = True

    button3 = Button(self.but_frame, text='Step', width=15, command=lambda :self.step_funct())
    button3.pack(side='right')
    button4 = Button(self.but_frame, text='Run', width=15)
    button4.pack(side='right')
    button4.bind("<Button-1>", self.butt_press)
    button4.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.butt_release)

def butt_press(self, event):
    self.butt_released = False
    self.run_funct()

def run_funct(self):
    if not self.butt_released:
        self.step_funct()
        self.root.after(10, self.run_funct)

def butt_release(self, event):
    self.butt_released = True
```

Comment: `butt_press` and `butt_release` will, next to self, also be given the event object, so using this will result in a similar error as the one in the question. You can either accept the event (`butt_press(self, event):`) and not use it, or throw it away with a lambda as in my answer. `button3` on the other hand really has no need for the lambda. Since it passes no arguments to `self.step_funct` just using `command=self.step_funct` is fine.

Comment: You are quite right, I completely forgot to include that in my answer. I've edited my answer to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

While [Benjamin James Drury](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27058197/3714930) is completely right, and using `time.sleep` and creating an infinite loop while using Tkinter (except for the Tkinter mainloop) are very bad ideas, I would like to point out the specific cause of the error you posted.

Your error comes from the line

```
button4.bind("<Button-1>", lambda :self.run_funct())
```

The bind function passes the event object to the function given, but your lambda does not accept any arguments. To let lambda accept the event, without using it you can use

```
button4.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e :self.run_funct())
```

This accepts the event as `e`, but does not use it.

The same goes for the next line ofcourse

Comment: Cheers for that, I don't actually know enough about lambda expressions to have felt confident talking about them in my answer.

Comment: lambda expressions have almost the same result as def statements (except for the lack of a name).  `def callback(): self.run_funct()` followed by `b4.bind("<Button-1>"), callback)` would have the same problem of `callback` needing to be defined with a dummy event parameter.

Comment: Thanks to both fhdrsdg and Benjamin James Drury. fhdrsdg, I especially appreciate that you have patiently helped me with my many TKinter questions that I have posted on here. I am new to TKinter and have been learning it over the past few weeks so it is a process.